# Criteria for a linear system of equations to have integer solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diophantine-equations

Suppose we have a linear system of equations given in matrix form as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \newline
d & e & f \newline
g & h & i
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \newline
y \newline
z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p \newline
q \newline
r
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$ where $a, b, c, \cdots, h, i, p, q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What are the conditions under which the system in Eqn. $(1)$ is Diophantine (i.e., $x,y,z$ has integer solutions)?

Here is what I came up with:

1. If $\Delta = \left| \begin{matrix}
   a & b & c \newline
   d & e & f \newline
   g & h & i
   \end{matrix} \right| = 1$ then $x, y, z$ are integers.
2. More generally, if $\Delta x = \left| \begin{matrix}
   p & b & c \newline
   q & e & f \newline
   r & h & i
   \end{matrix} \right|, \Delta y = \left| \begin{matrix}
   a & p & c \newline
   d & q & f \newline
   g & r & i
   \end{matrix} \right|, \Delta z = \left| \begin{matrix}
   a & b & p \newline
   d & e & q \newline
   f & h & r
   \end{matrix} \right|$ are **all** divisible by $\Delta$ then $x, y, z$ are integers.

Is there any other alternative or succint way to express this?

Comment: Are $a, b, c, ... i, p, q, r$ all integers?

Comment: Yes. Question edited to clarify coefficients and constants are integers.

Answer (score -1):

If $a,b,c,...i,p,q,r$ are all integers, then $x,y,z$ have integer solutions when $p$ is divisible by $ \gcd(a,b,c)$, $q$ is divisible by $ \gcd(d,e,f)$, and $r$ is divisible by $ \gcd(g,h,i)$. This condition is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. For e.g.: solve $x - 3 y + 3 z = -4, 
2 x + 3 y - z = 15, 
6 x - 3 y - 12 z = 12$. The GCDs of the coefficients of the equations are 1, 1, 3 respectively. 1 divides -4, 1 divides 15 and 3 divides 12. But $x = 197/55, y = 146/55, z = 7/55$ are not integers.

Comment: You're right. The GCD condition is necessary but not sufficient.